# Why is Double.parseDouble(scan.next()) so much faster than scan.nextDouble()?

Tags: java, file-io, double, java.util.scanner

So I have a file to read in and I know how the data will be set out. For example I know that the first token of each new line is going to be a double.

I had been using a Scanner and was simply using scan.nextDouble() to read in the double however I was told of Double.parseDouble(scan.next()) instead which sped up the process of reading in the data from the file from 30 seconds down to ~5 seconds.

The same happened with scan.nextInt() vs. Integer.parseInt(scan.next()).

In the file I was reading it went int double int int for each line for about 40,000 lines.

So what makes it so much faster?

Comment: Q: Can you describe the input (#/items per line, #/lines read, whether you're reading from a text file, etc)?

Comment: Ok I added that info, I didn't think it was entirely relevant that's all, so I had tried to word the question so it was a bit more general added now though.

Answer (score 5):

It's all because scan.nextDouble() find the nearest Doublelike value from the following Stream. it can not sure the next string value will be a doublelike value, for example

s = "abcde1234.5"
scan.nextDouble(s) will be 1234.5 but Double.parseDouble(scan.next()) will throw an error.

more details you will find in the source code.

Comment: +1 - and before it throws the error it has to put the characters back into the scanner buffers.  So you have the additional overhead of pushback buffering to deal with.

Answer (score 5):

The Scanner `next<Type>` methods are doing additional work besides simply reading in the next token and calling the appropriate parser.  First they check against a regular expression that the token is valid for that type, then they massage it to deal with locale-specific bits (such as group separator, decimal separator, etc.), then finally pass that to the parser.

If you are sure that your input is in the exact format you describe and you don't need to account for any potential differences caused by the input coming from a different locale, etc., then by all means use the optimization you were informed of.